# Splice in Clojure

Tags: clojure

is there a single function for getting "from x to y" items in a sequence?

For example, given `(range 10)` I want [5 6 7 8] (take from 6th to nineth, or take 4 from the 6th,). Of course I can have this with a combination of a couple of functions (eg `(take 4 (drop 5 (range 10)))`), but is seems strange that there's not a built-in like pythons's `mylist[5:9]`. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[subvec](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/subvec) for vectors, primarily since it is O(1).  For seqs you will need to use the O(n) of take/drop.

Answer (score 1):

From a philosophical point of view, the reason there's no built-in operator is that you don't need a built-in operator to make it feel "natural" like you do in Python.

```
(defn splice [coll start stop]
  (take (- stop start) (drop start coll)))

(splice coll 6 10)
```

Feels just like a language built-in, with exactly as much "new syntax" as any feature. In Python, the special `[x:y]` operator needs language-level support to make it feel as natural as the single-element accessor.

So rather than cluttering up the (already crowded) language core, Clojure simply leaves room for a user or library to implement this if you want it.

Answer (score 0):

`(range 5 9)`, or `(vec (range 5 9))`.

(Perhaps this syntax for `range` wasn't available mid-2012.)